# IC identification - Analog Devices IC with top marking S 0Z - 10 pin SMD IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I need help identifying this 10 pin SMD IC with just "S 0Z" as top marking.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a [ADG736LBRMZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG736L.pdf).

[image]

Search on the Analog Devices website gave this info
https://www.analog.com/en/search.html?q=*